# Magento2: Exception invalid block

Tags: magento2, blocks, exception

I have installed my module in a server in app/code folder and I executed

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

and

> bin/magento di:compile

and after I show this error:

[image]

The block is in Block folder.

I use it in front layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Oct8ne\Oct8ne\Block\Oct8neJS" template="Oct8ne_Oct8ne::oct8nejs.phtml" name="oct8nejs" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

In localhost works fine. I tried to flush cache, recompile di, deploy static files, delete var folders... any idea?

Comment: Also delete content of pub/static and execute all commands again. Also check permission.

Comment: permissions for?

Comment: Permission on var and pub folder

Comment: permissions 755?

Comment: try with 755 and if didnt work then try with 777